# System restarts when trying shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I met this problem on title earlier this summer on Ubuntu 14.04, then I switched to Mint 17 and initially I didn't face this problem, but after 2 months it started to happen again. Any clues about what can cause this?

Comment: You do not provide enough detail to go on. Have you tried running: sudo shutdown -h now

Comment: I've been using graphical interface, and no error messages are present, so I don't know what further detail I can give. Maybe one important thing to say is, it doesn't happen every time I try to shutdown, it's about once in 4 or 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

this thing maybe happen due to some malfunction in your hardware.before changing any system default setting check that your PSU, is working good..some short circuit can cause this types of issue !!